# Flash AS3 get parent frame reference from inside a function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling

This is my code in Flash/AS3, in a frame's action:

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

function loading(e:Event):void{

    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    if (total == loaded){

       var splashTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
       splashTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, splashTimer1);
       splashTimer.start();
       function splashTimer1(evt:TimerEvent):void
       {
          //remove the enter frame event listener here
          this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
          gotoAndPlay("3");
       }

    }

}
```

I want to remove the enter frame event listener (`loading()`), inside that `splashTimer` event handler, before redirecting to frame 3. As you can see, I used:

```
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
```

But it throws me a run-time error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: removeEventListener is not a function.
    at Function/<anonymous>()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

This is because I believe it is referring the `splashTimer1` function by "this".

How can I refer to parent frame there, so that I can remove its event listener?

Comment: Maybe try removing `this.`, or storing `this` in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pull the function out and place it at the same level as `loading`:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading); 

function splashTimer1(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
   //remove the enter frame event listener here
   this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
   gotoAndPlay("3");
}

function loading(e:Event):void{

var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

if (total == loaded){

   var splashTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
   splashTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, splashTimer1);
   splashTimer.start();
```

etc...

then `this` will refer to the MovieClip instead of the nested function.

You could also add a go-between var like:

```
if (total == loaded){

  var splashTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
  splashTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, splashTimer1);
  splashTimer.start();

  var theMC:MovieClip = this;

  function splashTimer1(evt:TimerEvent):void
  {
     //remove the enter frame event listener here
     theMC.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, theMC.loading);
     theMC.gotoAndPlay("3");
  }
```

etc...

but I like the first approach better.

Comment: Thanks a ton, WiseOldDuck. I followed first approach, and it worked perfect...!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what is happening in your code.

When we declare a function in **addEventListener** like the following ( or the way you did )

```
object.addEventListener(event, function(){


});
```

the function will be created in global namespace and inside the function `this` will refer to global object. Usually we use a proxy variable to store the instance of the object in similar situations.      So it can be fixed by doing the following

```
var _this = this;
var splashTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
splashTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, splashTimer1);
splashTimer.start();

function splashTimer1(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    //remove the enter frame event listener here
    _this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
    gotoAndPlay("3");
}
```

But usually we do this in Javascript.

The structure of your code has to be changed. Please see the anwser posted by @WiseOldDuck. That is the way to do it in Actionscript